# New line in JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript

I've seen a few questions about how to add a new line in JavaScript strings. Most of them are suggesting to use `\n`. I tried that but the new line is not inserted on my HTML.

Instead I get the following:

```
<strong>This is the first line 
 This is the second line</strong>
```

This is my string:

```
var myString = "This is the first line \n This is the second line";
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/oj2ajnxd/4/)**

Any idea on how I can get a 
 inserted on my HTML?

Comment: So, you want to do a new line in HTML or in js alert? First can be acheived by <br/>, second by \n

Comment: @kapilyadav exactly thats my issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have the new line in html you need some element like `<br />`. In fact, each block styled element will do, but `<br />` wont add any margin/padding by default, as f. i. a `<p>` or `<h3>` would. Anyway, breaking a line html requires any element, since "\n", "\t" and so on are ignored by the browser.

Comment: I realize this is pedantic, but it is Stackoverflow after all: the `<br>` tag in HTML does not need a self-closing `/`, though it doesn't hurt anything (because HTML parsers *always* accept but ignore the XML self-closing tag syntax).